# I need help with this riddle. "Where is Jim?"

Tags: riddle, wordplay

It's probably just an anti-riddle, but I'm still too dumb to figure it out.

> [image]

Comment: what's the source of this 'riddle'? it looks like a bad doodle to me!

Answer (score 11):

Jim is at:

> Position c09f6h (788982 decimal) offset in the JPG file contains the string **JIm**

Answer (score 3):

Is this:

> Alice taking to Bob about their long lost cousin, Jim?

Answer (score 1):

This is weird but is it this?

> The 'house' represents an arrow and the 'skirt and legs' of the person on the top represents an arrow without a base. The 'legs' of the person on the bottom represent an arrow without two bases. Looking at the arrows from the point of view that they are progressively getting reduced will order them 1,2 and 3 which will allow us to read the word Jim and if you look in between the clouds on the keyboard you will see the letters for the word Jim. Take note of how far to the left the arrows are and take note of the number allocated to the arrows...see that on the keyboard the middle character is J and more to the left than M and I? The left most arrow in the drawing is allocated 1 in the reading order and is also farther to the left than the other two arrows just like on the keyboard. The second character I is above M just like the two people and they are also almost inline with each other like I and M on the keyboard. To finish, all we need to do is look at the picture from a 3d perspective and spin around the people so that the 1st arrow is between them and voila!

Answer (score 1):

> I'm here looking at the picture :)